# watchOS Health Kit - Opting out of Activity ring contribution

Tags: watchkit, healthkit, watchos, hkhealthstore

Is it possible to run an HKWorkoutSession on Apple Watch, but not let that count towards any of the activity rings?

This makes particlar sense for the 'MindAndBody' workout activity type which could be seated or reclined meditation. Users do not want that counting towards their exercise ring, for obvious reasons - however they also want access to all of the in-session notications they get thanks to the HKWorkoutSession enabling our app to function in the background (amidst other benefits).

Has anyone encountered this before, and does anyone have a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: I still find that very disturbing. Is there now, three years later, any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to prevent HKWorkoutSessions from counting towards Activity. You should file a bug with Apple to request this enhancement.